# Why "paid for by" instead of "paid by"?

Tags: phrase-usage

I have seen following sentence:

> Text VOTE to 00000,
> Paid for by XXX for Presiedent, Inc.

Why it is "paid for by" instead of "paid by" in this particular sentence?

Could someone provide a complete, rephrased sentence for my understanding?

---

**Edits**

This question comes from the following source:

> https://www.youtube.com/Donaldtrump/videos:
>
> Text VOTE to 88022, paid for by Donald J. Trump for President, Inc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The electoral communication or message has been paid for by a group called "XXX for President, Inc".

You pay *for* goods or services.  You don't pay goods or services.

> Paid for by XXX for President, Inc.

i.e. "This communication was paid for by XXX for President, Inc."

Put another way, "XXX for President, Inc. paid for this message."

Comment: You _pay_ a sum of money, but _pay for_ a service.

Comment: In this case, XXX pays ***on behalf of*** someone or something else (as well as paying the bill or paying for the service, whichever of those we choose to ***infer*** from the context).

Answer (score 4):

The "object" of transitive (prepositionless) ***to pay*** can be...

> 1 - an actual amount paid
> 2 - a bill/demand for payment
> 3 - someone/something to whom payment is made

The ***reason*** for the payment (the thing being paid ***for***) must be preceded by that preposition.

---

But in OP's exact context, there's no reference to any of my 3 common object types for a *transitive* usage (without ***for***), nor is there any explicit reference to *"**this text-based voting system**"* (which XXX paid for).

Most native speakers would probably choose to include the extra preposition in *paid **for** by XXX* because if we have to "conjure up" a suitable object for the verb ***to pay*** here, it's easier to settle on *"**this text-based voting system**"** (an example of which we're looking at), rather than *"**the bill for producing this system**"* (which doesn't directly concern us).

Perhaps partly because it's followed by ***for** President, Inc* (a completely different preposition usage where ***for*** means ***on behalf of***), I think it's at least "acceptable" *in this exact context* to omit ***for*** after ***paid***. We have to infer the subject anyway, so we may as well infer *"the **cost** of this system"* rather than just *"this system"* if that avoids the slightly confusing/awkward use of ***for*** in two different ways in close proximity.

---

EDIT:
What I've written above changes if there's an actual organisation called **XXX for President** - where those 3 words represent a ***proper noun*** that shouldn't be syntactically deconstructed here (it's just a "label"). In that case, I'd definitely keep the preceding instance of ***for***. But even then, I think it would be unreasonable to say that discarding it was somehow "syntactically invalid".

Comment: Thank you this is helpful. I have added the source of the sentence.

Comment: Well, I'm not going to change my answer now you've edited the question to make it obvious that there's only one "agent" involved here (an organisation called "**Donald J. Trump for President, Inc.**", not one outfit called "**XXX**" making payment on behalf of another outfit called "**President, Inc.**"). I think my final "EDIT" section covers that aspect well enough.

Comment: This is the perfect explanation I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @SzélLajos: I sometimes complain that the built-in text search facilities on SO sites don't work very well for *questions about the English language* (because people are often looking for "little" words like prepositions ***for, by,...*** which the text indexing facilities largely ignore as just "noise words"). But it seems like they worked for you, if you managed to find this answer from a few years back to resolve a *current* issue!

Comment: Absolutely! Paid for by meaning - #4 hit on Google search